# I can't push because local repository out of date, but I can't pull the data

Tags: ios, xcode, git

so I am trying to use bitbucket for the remote repostitory, after making repository on their website, I am trying to push my local repository

but I  can't push the data because it is said local repository out of date in my Xcode
[image]

when I try to pull data from bitbucket, is seems all button and option are disable
[image]

the thick box and push button disable.

here the status from the terminal
[image]

I also have tried to pull from terminal
[image]

I am stuck, what should I do ?

Comment: You can probably fix this directly from Xcode, but if I had this problem, I would check the Git Bash to see what is happening.  Just type `git status` from your current branch to see what is going on.

Comment: I have update and add the screenshot of my git status: it is said hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

Comment: Can you `git pull` from the command line?  Not sure why this is greyed out in Xcode, but if you can get past this via the Bash, then why not do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `git push` from Terminal fails with:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

and your `git pull` from Terminal fails with:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

which tells us what we need to know. Specifically, **you have made a local repository that is entirely unrelated to the remote repository.**

This happens when you start a *new* Git repository locally, by running `git init` and then adding and committing some files into the new repository.  This new repository has no relationship with existing repositories.<sup>1</sup>

Then, you run `git remote add origin url` in your local repository, telling your Git that your local repository is directly related to the Git repository at *url*.  Your Git believes you.  (This is not the only way to get to this point, but is probably the way you did get to this point, even if you did it through Xcode.)

Once you have these two unrelated Gits ready to talk to each other, you get your Git to call up its supposed-brother (cousin? mother? whatever it might be) Git and talk with it.  With `git push`, your Git suggests that they take your new commits that add on to theirs—but yours *don't* add on to theirs, so they say: *no, this is not a fast-forward: your commits are not properly related to mine.*  With `git pull`, your Git obtains their commits, then you have your Git run `git merge` to combine your commits with their relatives from the other Git.  Your Git says: *whoa, wait, these commits aren't related!  I can't marry these two!*

There are multiple different ways to fix this.  Which one to use depends on what the original mistake was.  Should you have initially used `git clone` to clone the Bitbucket repository, so that your repository *is* related?  Or should you not have *created* the Bitbucket repository the way you did, so that the initial *Bitbucket* repository was *empty* and willing to be filled from your repository so as to *become* related?

Find out which of these is the case.  Then, armed with knowledge of where the original mistake was, come back to StackOverflow and search for how to fix the original mistake, while retaining whatever work you have done so far.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that a *totally empty* repository—one with no commits—also has no relationship with any other repository, but because it is a blank slate, it's perfectly happy to marry up with any other Git repository *at this point*.  That's how `git clone` works, for instance: when you clone some existing repository, you start by making a new, totally-empty repository.  Then you marry it with some other repository, which you normally call `origin`, using `git fetch` followed by `git checkout master`, and now the two repositories share all their `master` commits.